# finding normal subgroups of a dihedral group whose character table is given

Tags: group-theory, characters

my question is about character theory.

for example i have a character table of the dihedral group D12

which has 6 irreducible characters.so the character table is a

6*6 matrix.i also know all these (36 values) components in the

table.i need to find all the normal subgroups in the group

D12 by using the character table.where shall i start?

what are the steps to do that?

thanks for your help...

Answer (score 1):

Hint: each normal subgroup of a group $G$ is the intersection of the kernels of some of the irreducible characters of $G$.

Comment: how can i calculate kernel of a character,can you help?

Comment: $ker(\chi)=\{g \in G : \chi(g)=\chi(1)\}$, you should be able to read that off the character table. By the way, what text are you using studying group characters?

Comment: i think i start to read the given character table after some work,thanks.